# load tabs as hibernated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to learning js, angular and the technologies to to develop or modify a chrome extension, is there a way to load only one tab from a tab set and others as hibernated tabs ? (for chrome/vivaldi)

I'm trying to modify the extension "Session Manager" 
[Session manager at chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-manager/mghenlmbmjcpehccoangkdpagbcbkdpc)
I'm trying to open the tabs but only load one

this code is from "saved piined tabs" extension

```
        load: function (id, winid) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(id, function (set) {
            var tabs = set[id].tabs;
            chrome.tabs.query( {pinned: false,windowId: winid},
                function (cutabs) {
                var list = [];

                for (ind of cutabs) {
                    list.push(ind.id);
                }

                chrome.tabs.remove(list);

                for (inx of tabs) {
                    chrome.tabs.create({
                        windowId: winid,
                        url: inx,
                        active: false,
                        pinned: false
                    });
                }

                console.log('Loaded tabs');
                set_active(id, winid);

            } ) ;
        });
    },
```

Is there a way to only load one tab and others only open themn but don't load them ?

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: Probably `discarded: true` in the options of tabs.create.

Comment: @wOxxOm Chrome doesn't support specifying `discarded` in `create`. It's technically possible to call `discard` on newly created tabs, but it might not prevent them from starting to load.

Comment: I just found an extension that has a similar behavior to what it might be needed, 
 [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-multiple-urls/oifijhaokejakekmnjmphonojcfkpbbh) is called, **open multiple urls** , but I can't figure out the code, the extension loads the urls and if a checkbox is selected, it load the tabs but do not activate them, it only loads them as as suspended/hibernated, any help to figure out the code would be much appreciated